# How does the Python compiler preprocess the source file with the declared encoding?

Tags: python, encoding, python-internals

Let's say I have a Python 3 source file in cp1251 encoding with the following content:

```
# эюяьъ (some Russian comment)
print('Hehehey')
```

If I run the file, I'll get this:

`SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfd' in file ... on line 1 but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

That's clear and expected - I understand that, in general, cp1251 byte sequence can't be decoded with UTF-8, which is a default encoding in Python 3.

But if I edit the file as follows:

```
# coding: utf-8
# эюяьъ (some Russian comment)
print('Hehehey')
```

everything will work fine.

And that is pretty confusing.
In the 2nd example I still have in the source the same cp1251 byte sequence, which is not valid in UTF-8, and I expect the compiler should use the same encoding (UTF-8) for preprocessing the file and terminate with the same error.
I have read [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) but still don't get the reason it doesn't happen.

So, why my code works in the 2nd case and terminates in the 1st?

---

**UPD**.

In order to check whether my text editor is smart enough to change the file's encoding because of the line `# coding: utf-8`, let's look at the actual bytes:

(1st example)

```
23 20 fd fe ff fa fc ...
```

(2nd example)

```
23 20 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20 75 74 66 2d 38 0a
23 20 fd fe ff fa fc ...
```

These f-bytes are for cyrillic letters in cp1251 and they are not valid in UTF-8.

Furhermore, if I edit the source this way:

```
# coding: utf-8
# эюяъь (some Russian comment)
print('Hehehey')
print('эюяъь')
```

I'll face the error:

`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd ...`

So, unfortunately my text editor isn't so smart.
Thus, in the above examples *the source file is not converted from cp1251 to UTF-8*.

Comment: Which text editor or development environment do you use?

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3

Comment: It's likely that your text editor silently does the right thing and encodes your file as UTF-8, because it's clever enough to figure out what `# coding: utf-8` means in a Python file. Take a hex editor and look at the actual bytes in the file.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look like that. The source file is definitely in cp1251 in both examples. With or without a comment `# coding: utf-8` there are non UTF-8 bytes. For example, in both cases I have the '\xfd' byte which is a cp1251 'э' and which cause an error in the 1st example. So, there are must be a different explanation.

Comment: @Tomalak: Doesn't look like that's the case. I checked by making a file of the form described, then using `iconv` to convert it from UTF-8 to cp1251, so no editor was involved. The behavior was exactly as the OP describes: A `coding:` declaration, even one that just declares the implicit UTF-8 decoding explicitly, silenced the error, even when the file contained non-UTF-8 bytes, while failing to provide `coding:` declaration triggered the error. This is real, not an editor artifact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk of how the strict behavior for the default encoding is enforced. In [the tokenizer function, `decoding_gets`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f805628625e0cf4ee2d420735f7b15a93715aca/Parser/tokenizer.c#L619), if it didn't find an explicit encoding declaration yet (`tok->encoding` is still `NULL`), it does a character by character check of the line for invalid UTF-8 characters and pops the `SyntaxError` you're seeing that references PEP 263.

But if an encoding has been specified, [`check_coding_spec`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f805628625e0cf4ee2d420735f7b15a93715aca/Parser/tokenizer.c#L291) will have defined `tok->encoding`, and [that default encoding strict test](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f805628625e0cf4ee2d420735f7b15a93715aca/Parser/tokenizer.c#L619) is bypassed completely; it isn't replaced with a test for the declared encoding.

Normally, this would cause problems when the code is actually being parsed, but it looks like comments are handled in a stripped down way: As soon as the comment character, `#`, is recognized, [the tokenizer just grabs and discards characters until it sees a newline or `EOF`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f805628625e0cf4ee2d420735f7b15a93715aca/Parser/tokenizer.c#L1496), it's not trying to do anything with them at all (which makes sense; parsing comments is just wasting time that could be spent on stuff that actually runs).

Thus, the behavior you observe: An encoding declaration disables the strict file-wide character by character checking for valid UTF-8 that is applied when no encoding is declared explicitly, and comments are special-cased so that their contents are ignored, allowing garbage bytes in the comments to escape detection.